# How to reflash SMC firmware?

Tags: power-management

MacPro 2013 (MacPro6,1). The computer wake up by it-self after one or two minutes.
Re-install new OS. Reset Pram, SMC. Disconnect everything except power cord. Wifi disabled.
Auto-sleep after 4 minutes. Computer wake for 3 seconds, sleep for 2 minutes
and this cycles repeat forever. Last thing to try: re-flash SMC firmware.
Downloaded 2.20f18 (SMC 2.0) firmware [https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201518].
The software tell the Mac has already version 2.0 and don't let me re-install.

How can force re-flash ?

Comment: Can you install the original OS that came with the machine and then upgrade from there?

Comment: What happens if you boot into Safe Mode? Assuming it makes no difference, I'd try booting from another drive as a test. In fact, if you boot into macOS Recovery, does the behaviour persist? And, have you tried resetting the NVRAM and SMC a few times, just to be sure? As for reinstalling the original macOS, that's another option. Using the Shift-Option-⌘-R  option allows you to install the original (or oldest version still available) for your Mac. If doing this, then test again and move forward from there. Obviously, this assumes you have a Time Machine (or other) backup!

Comment: Additionally, check Activity Monitor for anything that shows as 'Preventing Sleep' & also switch off [& disconnect] Time Machine & Ethernet.

Comment: Re-install OS on external disk. Disable Wifi, Bluetooth, all notifications.
New Network without any interface (including Ethernet).
Nothing in Activity monitor hold the word "sleep".
Reseting Pram, SMC many times. Safe boot don’t help.

How can force re-flash ?

Comment: This sounds like [Power Nap](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204032).  You also can't downgrade the SMC firmware.  When you d/l an update with a firmware update included, it will *check*  the existing firmware's version.  If it's newer (which yours will be) , it will skip flashing it.  There's also nothing in NVRAM related to sleep so resetting it over and over will yield no results.

Comment: PowerNap is disable (in Energy Saver)

Comment: I don't want downgrade or upgrade firmware. I want re-flash with the same firmware to be sure the data is not corrupted.